# Send HTTP header from Orbeon XForm submission

Tags: orbeon, hl7-fhir

I have an API that depends on certain HTTP Headers for specific behavior. Example would be HTTP Header `If-Matches` on a POST to support updating only if version matches the value of `If-Matches`.

How would I send these HTTP headers from an Orbeon XForms submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xf:submission` element supports a nested `xf:header` element, which allows you to set custom headers. For example:

```
<xf:header>
    <xf:name>If-Matches</xf:name>
    <xf:value>whatever value</xf:value>
</xf:header>
```

The name and value can be dynamic using the `value` attribute. You can use many `xf:header` children elements. For more, see [The header Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#submit-header) from the XForms 1.1 specification.