# Orbeon forms: add authorization header to submission not working

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to add a header to an existing submission, as the endpoint resides in Azure API management and requires a "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" header.

The submission element looks as follows:

```
<xf:submission id="OrganisationStructureService-submission" class="fr-service"
                           ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                           resource="https://securextst-api.securex.eu/sssservices/employerservice/api/firm/0000000128/identification"
                           method="get"
                           serialization="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                           mediatype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                           replace="instance"
                           instance="fr-service-response-instance">
                <xf:header>
                    <xf:name>Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key</xf:name>
                    <xf:value>dummykey</xf:value>
                </xf:header>
            </xf:submission>
```

When reading other answers like [Send HTTP header from Orbeon XForm submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031073/send-http-header-from-orbeon-xform-submission) this should work, but I keep getting an 403 saying I didn't fill in the Subscription-key when I use the test dialog.
When doing the exact same request using Postman, it works so the error must be somewhere in my XML.

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but can't say what.

Comment: I am wondering if you've been hitting issue [#4606](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4606), which is fixed in 2019.2.3 and 2020.1.x. Are you by any chance using an earlier release? -Alex

Comment: Hi @harm-securex, did you get the `<xf:submission>` to send the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header, as needed, or maybe found another way to deal with this? If not, is upgrading to (or at least testing if this works with) 2020.1.x an option for you? -Alex

Comment: @avernet we are apparently running Orbeon 2017, so I guess that's why this happens. Is there any workaround? We are not actually the ones maintaining the platform so we have no control over upgrades..

Comment: Got it, then it seems that the problem you're having could be explained by issue [#4606](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4606), which, as mentioned earlier, has been fixed in 2019.2.3 and 2020.1.x. I don't see any workarounds, other than upgrading Orbeon Forms. So my recommendation really would be to upgrade to 2020.1.x, which was released last year, and by now is quite stable. Would that be a possibility for you?